# After upgrading to 1.9.3.1 via Magento Connect, check for updates stopped working

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, https

After upgrading from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.1 using Magento Connect, starting it o Mage All package (yes, it worked), my "check for updates" ha just stopped working.

When trying to check for updates, nothing is shown, just an empty column.

Bitnami Container @ Ubuntu 14.04 LTS @ Azure

Answer (score 2):

I didn't go deep on why is it happening, but I find out that changing Curl requests from HTTPS to HTTP it worked again.

To do that I modified this file:
/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php (line 371)

Changing this method signature from

```
protected function makeRequest(... $https = true)
    {
```

to

```
protected function makeRequest(... $https = false)
    {
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Finally a solution that works, thank you for this.